# Docusign NodeJS EnvelopeViews: createRecipient UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I call the GET envelope recipients API
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/cf70dfa7-a861-4029-b149-5360c090ebfa/envelopes/4de0ca11-e07b-4ff0-936f-cdd37ff18ed2/recipients
and it returns clientUserId, userId, email, etc. Odd thing is even though I'm sending it to myself, it returns a different user id than the one I sent with.

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "recipientSuppliesTabs": "true",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "name": "michael",
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "",
            "email": "email@email.email",
            "recipientId": "2",                  //idk why this is 2
            "recipientIdGuid": "smth",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "fdbb65f9-ea71-4e59-8374-0e1952c70e0a",
            "clientUserId": "random",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "roleName": "signer",
            "status": "sent",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "recipientType": "signer"
        }
    ],etcetc
}
```

Using those I call the POST /view/recipient API and insert all those same things

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "HTTPBasicAuth",//I've tried this and password
  "clientUserId": "random",
  "email": "userid", //Tried both user ID's, and email + name, didnt work
  "recipientId": "2",     //same as above
  "returnUrl": "http://localhost:3001/marketplace",
  "userName": "userid"//tried same thing, and leaving this blank, gave another error
}
```

but it gives the error code

```
{
    "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
    "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what your second call should be based on your first call:

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "none",
  "clientUserId": "123456",
  "email": "email@email.email", 
  "returnUrl": "http://localhost:3001/marketplace",
  "userName": "michael"
}
```